# How to avoid large memory consume custom loss function in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, backend, loss-function

I defined a custom loss function in keras. In this custom loss function I extract non-contiguous values from `y_pred` as it follows:

```
sel_row = tf.constant([[2],[5],[8]])
row_tmp = y_pred
selected = tf.transpose(tf.gather_nd(tf.transpose(row_tmp), sel_row))
```

With this I just select column from the tensor. Now, if I do the same but for contiguos columns, i.e `row_tmp[:, 2:5]`, I have no problems, but with not continuos columns I get:

```
/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/indexed_slices.py:424: 
UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. 
This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
```

Everything works, but it would be nice to have a better method to not then consume too much memory.

I tried to change `tf.constant` with `tf.Variable` but this error occurs:

`ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.`

Any tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```py
selected = tf.gather(row_tmp, tf.squeeze(sel_row, axis=1), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working without warning right now. But what do you think is the reason behind this difference ? I thought use ``tf.gather``'s fault but it is not like this

Comment: @Cla I'm not really sure, afaik indexed slices are usually used for gradient computation, it is a "compressed" representation for sparse tensors. My feeling is that the gradient of `tf.gather_nd` uses indexed slices and `tf.transpose` forces a conversion from that into a dense tensor, but I can't tell for sure... Tbh it is a relatively low implementation detail, and the warning is probably not too useful by itself for most users.